# Facebook oauth redirection is not working properly

Tags: facebook, hash, facebook-oauth

Today my application started to fail on Facebook oauth when my redirect URI has a hash string. Until yesterday it worked. Here the scenario:

On redirect to Facebook the url:

> www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=441044735940116&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myapp.com%2Fpt%2Fregister.html%23JA4BqoGbVnvw1OXky%7CMCwCCd6buzlvyTY9sg4JMzyQtJp9YLz8AhRNwKnj5G2dmIymLw4UK1ouSB9S0w%3D%3D&scope=email,user_birthday,user_location&response_type=token

Facebook returns me with:

> www.myapp.com/pt/register.html#access_token=BAAGRILrQ1hQBAP80ZCpK8p0d24e50tqoR8ZAR8nwhAfSYXN5U0h888ILWzpOYUM7lEYtUdbNU4hRm06t7ABBdZCMsiY7JgEqDPB9SImj7QOSAcsbJmOW3u652CyOhqvO9O7O1qdxYH8ANPuA9USEpC7ThyLCJXocxZB3c7bZB186JHhwbKeesRfOyPDXSaGQiqEwQbpDiF8MBi0jBgLD4&expires_in=6462

When it should return:

> www.myapp.com/pt/register.html#JA4BqoGbVnvw1OXky|CMCwCCd6buzlvyTY9sg4JMzyQtJp9YLz8AhRNwKnj5G2dmIymLw4UK1ouSB9S0w==&access_token=BAAGRILrQ1hQBAP80ZCpK8p0d24e50tqoR8ZAR8nwhAfSYXN5U0h888ILWzpOYUM7lEYtUdbNU4hRm06t7ABBdZCMsiY7JgEqDPB9SImj7QOSAcsbJmOW3u652CyOhqvO9O7O1qdxYH8ANPuA9USEpC7ThyLCJXocxZB3c7bZB186JHhwbKeesRfOyPDXSaGQiqEwQbpDiF8MBi0jBgLD4&expires_in=6462

Basically Facebook oauth is not sending my hash back to me. Anyone knows why?

Is it related to the issue below?

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/449931225075123